# Is it possible to get a national visa of one Schengen country after reaching duration limit of national visa of another country?

Tags: visa, germany, schengen, lithuania

I have Lithuanian national visa. Its duration is limited by 1 year in a row. (After a year there should be a pause for at least 6 months before new Lithuanian national visa.) And I'm close to reaching this limit. However I have a job offer from Germany. But the contract will become available after the end of my visa term only. So the first question is:

*Am I eligible to apply for German national visa (right after having 1-year Lithuanian national visa)?*

If the answer is *negative*, then I have the second question:

*Does it make sense to apply for Lithuanian residence permit for futher applying for German blue card?*

Comment: I believe you should ask this on Expatriates SE, they know more about long-term visa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I eligible to apply for German national visa (right after having 1-year Lithuanian national visa)?

Yes.  National visas are governed by national law, so they're essentially independent.

> Does it make sense to apply for Lithuanian residence permit for futher applying for German blue card?

Possibly.  If you want to apply for your German visa in Lithuania, and you need to apply for the residence permit to be able to stay in Lithuania, then you should apply for the residence permit.